# How to concatenate similar groups of blocks during tangle with noweb syntax?

Tags: org-mode, literate-programming, tangle

I used to have a literate configuration file structured as follows:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle "/tmp/out.el" :noweb yes

;; requirements
<<require>>

;; other
<<execute>>

#+END_SRC

* FOO

Here goes all the snippets of code related to module FOO.

#+NAME: require
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(require 'foo)
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: execute
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(foo-setup)
#+END_SRC

* BAR

Here goes all the snippets of code related to module BAR.

#+NAME: require
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(require 'bar)
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: execute
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(bar-setup)
#+END_SRC
```

With previous versions of Org-Mode, I obtained the following file:

```
;; requirements
(require 'foo)
(require 'bar)

;; other
(foo-setup)
(bar-setup)
```

Notice how all blocks named `require`  (resp. `execute`) are grouped together.
With Org-Mode 9.2.3 (Emacs 26.1), I only have the blocks related to `foo`:

```
;; requirements
(require 'foo)

;; other
(foo-setup)
```

Is it a case of [*"the update broke my workflow"*](https://xkcd.com/1172/)? Is there an easy way to obtain the same result as previously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this can be fixed by using `:noweb-ref` instead:

```
* FOO

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :noweb-ref require
(require 'foo)
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :noweb-ref execute
(foo-setup)
#+END_SRC

* BAR

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :noweb-ref require
(require 'bar)
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :noweb-ref execute
(bar-setup)
#+END_SRC
```